# PHP Googlemaps showing blank screen

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

Okay, so I have searched and tried different methods, and still don't know why when I add in the 'name' to my code, it stops working (just shows blank page), but if I remove 'name' it works just fine.

```
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE e_lat != ''";
$result = $link->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $idx = $row['IDX'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $lat = $row['e_lat'];
    $lon = $row['e_long'];
    echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon, $idx, $name);\n");
}
?>

function addMarker(lat, lng, idx, name) 
 {
    var html = 'IDX: ' + idx + '<br>Name: ' + name;
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: html,
                maxWidth: 300
            });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id: idx,
    position: pt,
    icon: icon,
    map: map,
    content: html
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
    {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
 }
```

Comment: @chris85 thanks.. didn't know that! It is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$name` is a string so it needs to be quoted. Use:

```
echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon, $idx, '$name');\n");
```

You also should use the developer console in the future. That will help you debug these issues.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

(or if you are using another browser search for how to access its developer's tools, most browser today have some debugging feature in them)